# How to look into MS Assemblies

Tags: .net

I would like to look into some microsoft assemblies like "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" or "System.Core.dll" but dont know how to do it and if it is even possible.

I installed the .NET Reflector Extension without any help to solve my problem. Could anyone help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to take a look at .net's source code, try [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/). Although it has been available for download for ages, Microsoft recently released this browsable version (Feb 2014).

Here's the source code for the two assemblies you mentioned:

- [Microsoft.VisualBasic](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic)
- [System.Core](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core)

Related: [A new look for .NET Reference Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx)

Comment: That is what I was looking for and even better than decompiling it by myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Reflector has a menu option called `Open Global Assembly Cache`. Alternatively, search the file system for assembly names and you'll find the physical files. You can drag them into Reflector.